# I accidentally sent Dai to polygon contract. What can I do?

Tags: polygon

I accidentally sent Dai to `0x357D51124f59836DeD84c8a1730D72B749d8BC23` which is a polygon contract.

What can I do? Can I get it back?

I can see the $24,586 here: https://polygonscan.com/address/0x357D51124f59836DeD84c8a1730D72B749d8BC23

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking into the smart contract code, it will unfortunately be very hard/impossible to get your Dai back, except of you know the devs/Owner of the contract.

It's a proxy contract, meaning that they can "change" the code (point to another contract). If this newly deployed contract implement a function to withdraw from the contract itself yes, you could ask a refund.

The probability of this happening is extremely low.
If you don't know the devs, you probably will never see it again :/
Sorry for your loss!

Comment: Can you show me the code??

Comment: How would one find the dev for a contract?? Is there a source for that info?

Comment: You can fine the code here: [link](https://polygonscan.com/address/0x357D51124f59836DeD84c8a1730D72B749d8BC23#code). I did a little search but couldn't find any way to contact them... Be careful next time and always double check your contracts before sending some money ;)

Comment: With pleasure! I hope it's not a big loss :/

Comment: lol it'd be nice to have 25k back because we live in a world where that is a lot of pizza and rent

Comment: Yeah I saw the tx  dang